# Finding font which has letter A with verticall right side, similar to symbol: Æ

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm trying to get similar style as is in the Æ symbol:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86

But for standalone A letter, or it can be achieved with italics

Comment: What software are you using?  It's possible to skew text using graphic design software such as Inskcape [see example](https://imgur.com/jqBduJA).

Comment: I could write the letters in vector completely from scratch at that point, but i would prefer have at least good starting point with a existing font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a font? I guess you want to use the asymmetric A in an editable text and it will occur in numerous places, so making your text as outlined image is not your first choice.

If you input the image of the wanted A to an online font identifier, like Font Squirrel you'll find numerous candidates. They are italic cuts in font families. An example:

[image]

Font identifiers are owned by font sellers, so do not expect too many free options to be shown. You must search manually sites like dafont.com to see more free fonts.

Font family Heading Now is free and it contains cuts which have the wanted A.  Unfortunately Heading Now is free only for personal usage. You must buy a paid license if you want legally make something for others or get money by using that font.

You can also draw the needed A and use it as inline graphics if your writing program supports such thing. A properly drawn custom letter can well flow acceptably among other text when the text is edited. Of course, no automatic finesses of pro typesetting (kerning, optical balancing) do happen.

Then you can make an edited version of an existing font. Beware, it's a swamp! Edited versions of commercial fonts are generally illegal and if your writing program or PDF maker embeds such font to a file that you give to others you are distributing a pirate font. Some 100% free fonts exist and the author of the font may even allow creating edited versions. The exact conditions for a legal edited version are written in the license file.